Colourising atoms from an imported PDB
I am using Cycles Renderer and importing a PDB file of a chemical structure. I want to be able to manipulate the individual atom balls and sticks. I can select atom groups and add materials, and the material preview looks okay, but these changes are not imposed on the image that actually renders. Am I doing something wrong?
I'm starting with a blank slate and just importing the pdb. this is not a specific pdb file problem either. the pdb is generated in MolView then exported as a pdf to OpenBabel then imported into Blender.


Can you post more images or maybe share your Blender project file? Your question isn't totally clear to me.  Instructions for sharing.

Are you using BioBlender or Molecular Nodes to import the .pdb file? Could you share the .pbd file?

@DireWolf I looked at it just now and the colors seem to be the same in material preview and rendered image

Hi - thanks so much for looking - I am utterly confused then.  That's absolutely not the case for me - I basically can't change the colour of anything in this blender

Could you write the version of Blender you are using ?

I just did a google search and from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkeHDsnIA2Y&list=PLfj1PQIVob0X0abyWkup1SY5eC-sgaTQL&index=3  from 7:50 onwards she explains how to change the material colour of an atom. Basically you have to select the appropriate part in the Outliner panel (Top right hand panel) and not directly from the 3D viewport.

If you are already familiar with some Blender basics another option may be more interesting to you and that is to change all the parts to mesh objects. To do that you would need to go into edit mode and separate all the parts into separate objects then in Object mode Convert to Mesh and finally join the parts again as they were before.

If needed, to convert to mesh this video at 4:50 from the same instructor  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zdi59AoVP6o

thanks very much all for your time....I am using blender 4.1.0 and the secret seemed to be the "create tab" at the right hand side and the access within this to atomic blender settings....many thanks

@DireWolf Could you please write an answer post for this with screenshots so we can close this question?

Hi Harry.  can you advise as to how I do that?

@DireWolf There is a text area below this comment section where you can input your answer. There are tools to add pictures/screenshots we well.
